# Passing and using a list in CodeDom dynamic method

Tags: c#, assemblies, codedom, csharpcodeprovider

I am trying to use a simple static method to return an object to dynamically evaluate an expression.  I have followed the advice outlined in the examples here: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RuntimeCompilation_2.aspx

For basic expressions this is working fine, but for ones that involve a .Contains() method I get an exception thrown.

Working Calls:

```
Console.WriteLine(DynamicCodeUtils.TestExpression("1 == 1 && (2 == 3 || 2 == 2) && 4 == 5");
Output: false

Console.WriteLine(DynamicCodeUtils.TestExpression("Math.Max(100,200)"));
Output: 200
```

Non-Working Call:

```
string _ArrayCheck = "\"1,2,3\".Split(',').ToArray().Contains(\"1\")";
Console.WriteLine(DynamicCodeUtils.TestExpression(_ArrayCheck));

Throws an exception - expected output would be "true"
```

Code:

```
public static object TestExpression(string Expression)
    {
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll");
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, GetCode(Expression));

        var cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("DynamicNS.DynamicCode");
        var method = cls.GetMethod("DynamicMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        return method.Invoke(null, null);
    }

public static string[] GetCode(string Expression)
    {
        return new string[]
        {
            @"
            using System;
            using System.Linq;

            namespace DynamicNS
            {
                public static class DynamicCode
                {
                    public static object DynamicMethod()
                    {
                        return " + Expression + @";
                    }
                }
            }"
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CompilerResults` type contains the property `Errors`. If you look into in, you will find:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is because types in the `System.Linq` namespace (like [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable)) are in the `System.Core.dll` assembly. If you add that, then your code will start working:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I had been trying to add/remove countless references and could not find the right combination.  Working flawlessly now.